# Object should keep its status

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-5

I am trying to figure out how to put an object to a function and return that
object with its original values.

It's part from my "framework"...

Here an simplified example:

```
var _objectToFunction = function (obj) {
        var F = function () { }
        F.prototype = obj
        return F
    }

var myclass = {
    a:"abc",
    print: function(){
      console.log("i am a func")
    },
    config: {
      path: "c:/bla"
   }
}

var fo = _objectToFunction(myclass)
var of = new fo()
of.config.path = "c:/ofpath"
of.z = "zzz"
of.a ="aaa"
console.log(of)

var fo2 = _objectToFunction(myclass)
var of2 = new fo2()
console.log(of2.z)
console.log(of2.a)
console.log(of2.config.path)
```

The output from console.log(of2.config.path) should "c:/bla", but is "c:/ofpath".

How can I do this right?

Comment: All `config` properties are references to the same object. If you want to have different `config` objects for different instances, you have to clone it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have tried to clone with Object.assign({}, obj), but it does't work, same result.

Comment: @pumi that wont work, as youre still overriding the (now cloned) myclass.config, so you need to do this for each instance...

Answer (score 1):

You may want to add a constructor (a function that is called, when an instance was created):

```
var _objectToFunction = function (obj) {
    var F = function (...values) {
      if( this.constructor) this.constructor(...values);
    }
    F.prototype = obj
    return F
}
```

So you can create a new config Object for each instance:

```
var myclass = {
constructor:function(addconf){
  this.config=Object.create(this.config);
  if(addconf) Object.assign(this.config,addconf);
},
a:"abc",
print: function(){
  console.log("i am a func")
},
config: {
  path: "c:/bla"
}
}
```

Now it behaves as wanted.

```
var parent=_objectToFunction(myclass);
var instance=new parent({ path:"changed"});
```

Or with standard object funcs:

```
var instance=Object.create(myclass);
instance.constructor({path:"changed"});
```